# XML http request, document.getelementbyID breaks javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, document, xmlhttprequest

I'm very new to XML but even so I managed to get a working script thanks to w3school's site that loads in information from the file, here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dom.asp . Unfortunately I've run into a little issue with a duplicate site and even though I've researched I haven't found an answer why.

The code is identical in a second site of mine besides the elementId names.

I'm using a wamp server, my XML file "PortfolioInfo.xml" is in the same directory as my index.html, I have a  tag inside of a  tag in my xml. I want to insert information from the  tag in my XML into my  HTML tag.

My Javascript is:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","PortfolioInfo.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("contactName").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

if I comment out the document.getElementById line the rest of my Javascript code doesn't break if it's not commented out if breaks. I've tried placing it in the HTML file itself at the end of the body tag.

the full HTML is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Portfolio: Darrell James</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aldrich' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="home">

</div>

<div id="about">
    <div id="aboutHome"><span class="arrow"><<</span></div>
    <div id="aboutSlide">
        <div id="aboutText">
            about
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="gallery">
    <div id="galleryHome"><span class="arrow"><<</span></div>
    <div id="gallerySlide">
        <div id="galleryText">
            gallery
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="contact">
    <div id="contactHome"><span class="arrow"><<</span></div>
    <div class="nobr" id="contactContent">
        <span id="contactName">
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="contactSlide">
        <div id="contactText">
            contact
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","PortfolioInfo.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.getElementById("contactName").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

</script>
</body>
```

It's not necessary I use XML but I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What error message do you get when the code breaks? Do the elements exists in the XML where you expect them?

Comment: I've made this complicated to follow sorry. There isn't an error code. The JavaScript in the bottom of the HTML there originally sat in Script.js declared just before. In Script.js I have a lot of JQuery doing other functions with this script sat at the top (which is standard JS not Jquery correct?) When it's in script.js the whole javascript file breaks like there's some syntax error or something. They are where I expect them in XML, <contact-info><name>Darrell</name></contact-info> is this correct nesting?

Comment: Have you tried to debug this using the debugger in the borwser? IE, press F12 to get to debugger. FF install FireBug and then F12 will activate the debugger. Chrome F12 runs the debugger.

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question, but have you checked to make sure xmlhttp.responseXML is actually filled with data and is the proper XML object type that contains the getElementsByTagName function in it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I'm in the debugger but I'm not really certain what I'm looking for to determine the problem with the script.

Comment: @Lochemage this is starting to sound pretty complicated to me now who's just started XML. The PortfolioInfo.xml is filled with data and has the <name> tag that JavaScript is asking for. If this isn't what you wanted to know I'm in the dark about an important area of XML.

Comment: @Darrell First of all look at what is returned into `xmlDoc` to check you have the data for the following statement in that variable and in the correct xml format. Set a breakpoint on the `xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;` line and then view the variable.

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is all kind of going over my head, however in the debugger I did find an error in the console that you and Bergi were looking for: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null " I'm checking XML and my original syntax and I don't see why it should return null. I'll paste my XML into the question now.

Comment: Looks like the XML is not getting loaded correctly when `responseXML` is `null`.

Comment: It sounds like I've made a silly little mistake somewhere doesn't it haha. The name's match up exactly and they're in the same directory, I'm currently googling debugging with chrome tutorials I've never actually done it before so I'll try put more information in where I can.

Comment: Okay I just made the biggest beginner mistake with XML, I had 2 tags outside of each other. I feel like such an idiot. Sorry for wasting your time guys I'll just go slam my head into a wall. Thanks for all the help though I learnt a lot and I'll definitely have to learn debugging with browsers properly sometime.

Comment: Use the `Network Inspector` tab of the chrome tools. What do you see, is the file getting loaded as expected?